# Is the "pending delete-vote" list complete?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete, 10k-tools

One of the moderator tools is the ["delete votes" list](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete). Does the "most votes" list (after expanding the small triangle) contain *all* posts with delete votes, or is it just a small sample?

If so, how are the posts chosen that are displayed on the list?

(Since a post needs at least one delete vote to be appear on the list, and most list items I see have only one vote, I started wondering whether the list contained *everything*.)

Comment: It's not all the posts, just a very short view. I don't think self-deleted posts appear for instance. (But can't find a reference for that.)

Comment: @Mat: Well, *deleted* posts don't appear at all, only those that have pending delete votes...

Comment: They do, in the "recent occurences" list

Comment: @Mat: In my experience, self-deletes don't show up there, no.

Comment: @Mat: Oh OK, I should clarify that I only mean the "most votes" list on the left.

Comment: MSE: [Restore the 10k ability to see all closed/deleted posts in a list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92979/restore-the-10k-ability-to-see-all-closed-deleted-posts-in-a-list) <- some history, can't find the exact rules though.

Comment: I've always found the delete tab too confusing to even bother doing delete votes on a regular basis. Why must it be such a terribly complex thing to delete a post? I bet 99% of all posts that received 5 _close_ votes could get instantly deleted (after say a grace period of 1 week when the op gets a chance to fix it) and the site would only be better for it.

Comment: @Lundin: Acually, I think something like that is already in place - the Community user regularly deletes posts that are closed and have non-positive score and no answers.

Comment: @Lundin reference http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006